# Android 7 (api 24) OnActivityResult from gallery, I can not intent to another class

Tags: android, android-intent, android-7.0-nougat

I know with Android 7 you can't pass File// but in this case I'm not doing that. For testing purposes, when a user selects a file, I just want to intent to another class. When I click a video, the app just stops responding so there isn't a crash log or anything. This is my onActivityResult method:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

            // OI FILE Manager
            String filemanagerstring = selectedImageUri.getPath();

            // MEDIA GALLERY
            String selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            if (selectedImagePath != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "THE PATHHHHHHHHH " + selectedImagePath);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        GalleryUpload.class);
               // intent.putExtra("path", selectedImagePath);
                startActivity(intent);
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: uncomment your putExtra line and then make sure you are using the intent properly on the destination activity

Comment: @WillEvers The problem is that I can not intent from this method

Answer (score 1):

Replace all of that with:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(), GalleryUpload.class)
              .setData(selectedImageUri)
              .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

This correctly handles both `file` and `content` `Uri` schemes, including passing along read access to `GalleryUpload`.

`GalleryUpload` can then use `getIntent().getData()` to retrieve the `Uri`, then use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`.

Comment: The problem is not with me obtaining the return results (uri/file/etc), the problem is with me intenting from the onActivityResult method. When I ran the code above, I got the same result. Even if I didn't get the uri from data, when I try to intent, the app still freezes.